# Standardising different response variables so I can compare effect sizes across response variables of different units

Tags: r

I want to standardise the following four response variables. This is so I can compare the slopes across the different variables to see when in a birds reproductive cycle is environmental effect most impactful. After googling it seems that standardising response variables is not often done but are there are big issues with me doing so?

My predictor variable in this case is `Native_biomass` and I want to include numerous confounding variables such as `Non_native_biomass + Distance_to_road + Distance_to_light + Anthropogenic_cover + Canopy_cover + Species`

```
Responses:
Egg_lay_date
Clutch_size
Chick_size
Fledgling_success
```

To do this, would i be right to use the `rstandard()` function? I'm a little confused as to how whether getting the standardised residuals is the same as standardising my response variable.

I've tried standardising using the Egg_lay_date response to begin:

`standardise.lm <- lm(Egg_lay_date ~ Native_biomass + Non_native_biomass + Distance_to_road + Distance_to_light + Anthropogenic_cover + Canopy_cover + Species, data=egglay_date_standard_test)`

```
standard_res <- rstandard(standardise.lm)
egglay_date_standard_test <- cbind(egglay_date_standard_test, standard_res)
summary(egglay_date_standard_test)
```

It seems to have worked but just not sure if this is the same as standardising my response variable?

```
 summary(egglay_date_standard_test)
    Nest_box      First_egg     Total_biomass   Native_biomass  Non_native_biomass   Species           Occupied_YN
 Min.   : 6.0   Min.   : 9.00   Min.   :10.00   Min.   : 0.00   Min.   : 0.00      Length:16          Min.   :1   
 1st Qu.:26.5   1st Qu.:17.00   1st Qu.:30.00   1st Qu.:15.00   1st Qu.: 0.00      Class :character   1st Qu.:1   
 Median :46.0   Median :19.00   Median :41.25   Median :16.88   Median :21.25      Mode  :character   Median :1   
 Mean   :40.5   Mean   :22.81   Mean   :38.75   Mean   :21.48   Mean   :17.27                         Mean   :1   
 3rd Qu.:55.5   3rd Qu.:25.25   3rd Qu.:50.62   3rd Qu.:28.12   3rd Qu.:28.12                         3rd Qu.:1   
 Max.   :66.0   Max.   :58.00   Max.   :57.50   Max.   :52.50   Max.   :37.50                         Max.   :1   
  standard_res            
 Min.   :-1.92983    
 1st Qu.:-0.55444   
 Median :-0.31608   
 Mean   :-0.04515     
 3rd Qu.: 0.34137   
 Max.   : 2.41618
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Extracting standardized residuals is **not** the same as standardizing your response variables (standardized residuals adjust the residuals to account for the influence the corresponding observation has on the response). It won't change the regression coefficient, which is what you want to compare across models (if I understand correctly).

In base R, the `scale()` function is the easiest way to standardize variables (by default, it subtracts the mean and divides by the standard deviation).

```r
lm(scale(Egg_lay_date) ~ ..., ...)
```

(where the first `...` is the rest of your formula and the second `...` is the other arguments to `lm`, such as `data`).

A reasonably efficient way to fit a bunch of scaled regressions would be (illustrating with the built-in `mtcars` data set):

```r
lm0 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl + vs + am + gear, data = mtcars)
scaled_regs <- list(
    mpg = update(lm0, scale(mpg) ~ .),
    disp = update(lm0, scale(disp) ~ .),
    wt = update(lm0, scale(wt) ~ .)
)
scaled_regs[["mpg"]]
```

(You could automate this still further, at the cost of making it harder to understand ...)

If you want to compare across *predictors* as well as across *responses* you should also scale your predictor variables.

Comment: Hi Ben, thank you for the advice here. The above works well for two of the models I want to compare as they are both LMs. However, the 2 others (Clutch size and Fledgling Success) are run using GLMS. Is there anything you might be able to suggest? My goal is to have 4 plots (one each for each response variable - lay date, clutch size, chick size and fledgling success) each showing how increasing native biomass affects the response. And I want to standardise them so I can compare slopes across plots and make direct comparisons re the scale of effect of native biomass on each response.

Comment: That seems a little challenging, since the GLMs will implicitly be estimating effects on a different scale (assuming/guessing logit for Fledgling Success, log for Clutch size). It's crude but maybe you can use (pseudo) R^2 to compare?  (R^2 measures for GLMM are available in several packages, see the GLMM FAQ ...). If you want to dig into this further I think it would be more appropriate as a [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) question ...

Comment: Hi Ben, many thanks for the response. The R^2 approach may be the best option for me. If I have the R^2 for each model (McFadden's R^2 for the GLMs) as below:

```Fledgling success - 0.3671377
Chick size - 0.3779727
Clutch size - 0.7308544
Lay day - 0.7796787```

I’m not so sure how to translate this to answer my question? The higher figure, the more impactful the main predictor (native_biomass) is? 

How could I perhaps visualise that if so for a visual aid re comparison?

Comment: Yes, higher R^2 suggests (although it's a bit loose!) "greater impact". (I don't have what I consider a **good** answer for this, it's not that easy ... Lower R^2 could mean **either** more noise in the response or less expected effect - but directly estimating magnitude of effect from different scales is hard) Some of the packages that compute R^2 include confidence intervals (maybe `r2glmm`?), that would be very good for a graphic. I do encourage a [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com) post, this is an interesting question ...

Comment: thanks Ben, I'll post up on CrossValidated now. Many thanks for your help on this so far.

Comment: One possibility would be to do all of the fits on the log scale (use log-transformed data for the LMMs, use a log-link for the binomial), in which case all of the estimates would be sensitivities ...

Comment: CrossValidated post - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/584382/how-to-compare-the-impact-of-one-predictor-variable-native-biomass-across-4-di